# How to get facebook photo album id for "Photo of My_Page"

Tags: facebook, wordpress, embed, photo

Regularly on blog/wordpress , I just type this short code-->[fbphotos id=46735712999xxxx size=small].

My problem is,  when some guest post a photo to my page timeline, I cannot retrieve any album "id". However, all photo share by guest have the same set number but doesn't have album id, sample as below:

Sample1: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=730394346983055&set=o.200225940174399&type=3&theater

Sample2: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10203935492737715&set=o.200225940174399&type=3&theater

you can see set=o.200225940174399 , is that possible using set number, if possible which code i need to use.

Regarding on my plan ,I want to make guest photo appear on my blog gallery.